# How to open the last modified document in a file?

Tags: c#

I'm new with C#. I have this piece of code and have no idea why it does not work.

I have a document in a `file`, I don't have the `file name`, but i do know it is the most recently changed `file` in this directory.

I want to open it (actually i just copy and past it in an another folder) but I am not sure this file is selected (because i can't open it)

Thank you.

```
private void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Admin\files");
    var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles() 
        orderby f.LastWriteTime descending select f).First();
    myFile.OpenRead();
}
```

(**PS**: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myFile)` don't work as well said invalid argument, i don't know  why ...)

Comment: What it is doint if it is not working? Any exceptions?

Comment: So,you want to copy that document to another path?

Comment: The code in your question will open the file in your application - it sounds like you want to open the file in its default program (for example `.docx` file is opened in MS Word). Is this correct?

Comment: if just copy and past it in an another folder, you can use copy function.

Comment: may you mean the path `C:\Users\Admin\documents`?

Comment: what ist the exception? what fails? if you run the programm in the debugger, what message shows the debugger?

Comment: That's the issue everything work fine, no exceptions, no messages showed but nothing happens when i click on my button.  

 
@M.Schena I just tried to translate from my langage, the path is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works for me even with `Process.Start()`.
But i choose the folder `"C:\Users\admin\documents"`, but this doesn't matter if the folder exists and you have the rights to read from it.

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\admin\documents");
var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
              orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
              select f).First();
Process.Start(myFile.FullName);
```

Comment: Works fine thanks to ".FullName". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jrsls U are welcome, glad to hear it works.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you if you just want to copy that file to another path:

```
private void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string originPath = @"C:\Users\Admin\files";
     string destinationPath = @"d:\";
     var directory = new DirectoryInfo(originPath);
     var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                   orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                   select f).First();

     File.Copy(Path.Combine(originPath, myFile.Name),
               Path.Combine(destinationPath,myFile.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
```

**OR**

```
public static FileInfo GetNewestFile(DirectoryInfo directory) {
   return directory.GetFiles()
       .Union(directory.GetDirectories().Select(d => GetNewestFile(d)))
       .OrderByDescending(f => (f == null ? DateTime.MinValue : f.LastWriteTime))
       .FirstOrDefault();                        
}
```

Just call it the following way:

```
FileInfo newestFile = GetNewestFile(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\directory\"));
```

and that's it. Returns a `FileInfo` instance or `null` if the directory is empty.
And also check the `access rights` for the particular folder.